# Put transparent form fields/text areas on an image in Openoffice Writer?

Tags: openoffice, forms

I'd like to create a few pages with a background image and (different) text at the same areas on the image. Think of invitation cards or recipes - there is some structure (recipient and location, or title and cooking duration), but the text always differs.

What's the best way to achieve that?

I can't find a way to move text areas to the place over the image where I need the text to be. New text areas are placed at the end of the current text, or at the selected text, and I didn't find a way to move them around.

Form fields always have a solid background. I need a transparent background so that the (sparse) lines of the background image are still visible (especially when the form field is not filled completely). There is no transparency option (such as RGBA) in the background color dialog for form fields.

Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Insert -> Frame -> Frame* and specify *Anchor* `To page`.

Under the *Transparency* tab, specify *Transparency* as `100%`.

[image: a transparent text frame]

There is an enhancement request for transparent form fields. 
 See. https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/91370/form-field-transparent-background/.